# Rails 4: how to redirect_to a subdomain action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, redirect, parameters

In my rails 4 application I am trying to redirect to a controller action which is routed to a subdomain while passing some parameters to it.

Here is what works, but what needs some improvement:

```
redirect_to "http://subdomain.lvh.me:3000/build"
```

As you can see, currently no paramters get passed to that url.
I'd like to pass `(id: params[:id]).`
I am wondering if there is a way to do this with the pathfinder as I am trying to access a subdomain action from my main domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add to the link params using interpolation like here

```
redirect_to "http://subdomain.lvh.me:3000/build/#{params[:id]}"
```

But you have to remember that `http://subdomain.lvh.me:3000` is you local url so you have to save true url somewhere in database/project if you want to have this project on production.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this without needing different code for development and production?

Comment: Yes, but just a bit. You can save you external links in rails config (easy but not very good) or use secrets.yml (nice and clean idea). and then you can use  `redirect_to "#{Rails.application.secrets.link_to_subdomain}/{#{params[:id]}"`

Comment: Thank you! @Argonus